# Power Pivot/Data model issue

Tags: database-design, query, pivot, excel, data

Good day,

I am facing two blocking points where I would need your insights please.

I have downloaded all my sheets in power query and made the necessary transformations, including creating a common Column ID on each sheet based on a project number and company ID (=Project number (IFS)). The goal is to create a report (in the form of a PivotTable with tabular form to display/align the data) that will relate the different sheets based on this Project ID. To create the report, I would like to create a data model and use PowerPivot object. Below is the idea of the desired report design: [image].

My first blocking point, once the data model is created and start using the power pivot, all the data that should be displayed in the different project number is put in line per project and duplicated in all the other project lines also.
For example, 'Inspection Activities.' All the data in the PivotTable ends up in a single row in sequence and duplicates for each Project ID. Below is a screenshot of the issue. Did I miss a step? Or is this a limitation of the system?"

[image]

My second blocking point is the below error. The sheet 'Nadia POs 2020-2023' lists a set of purchase orders by projects and companies. However, it contains replicated data in the 'Project ID (IFS)' column because for each project/company, we have multiple purchase orders.

When I try to establish the relationship, I realize that it is blocking. Do you see a way to bypass this error to be able to relate it to the rest of the sheets?

[image]
[image]